# @Binding with SwiftData - HowTo use Double value with a TextField

Tags: swiftui

I have a simple model class I want to use with SwiftData:

```
@Model
class Destination {
    var name: String
    var expenses: Double
    
    init(name: String = "", expenses: Double = 0.0) {
        self.name = name
        self.expenses = expenses
    }
}
```

I want to edit entries that are created, and for this I have created the following EditView, where I use @Bindable:

```
struct EditDestinationView: View {
    
    @Bindable var destination: Destination
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            TextField("Name", text: $destination.name)
            TextField("Expenses", text: $destination.expenses)
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Edit Destination")
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    }
}
```

The problem I have is the double value "expenses", which I can't use in TextField.

```
Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<Double>' to expected argument type 'Binding<String>'
```

Question:
What would be the best way to read/update destination.expenses with the value from the textField?

Comment: The question is not particularly related to SwiftData. There are `TextField` initializers with `value` and `format`.

Comment: Ah, you're absolutely right ... I was thinking too complicated in terms of SwiftData and @Binding :-( Thx a lot for your hint vadian.

Answer (score 0):

As vadian mentioned, it's just simple:

```
TextField("Expenses", value: $destination.expenses, format: .number)
```